# When is the latest I can kill Mr. House?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Considering that I'm going the Wild Card: Change in Management path, when is the latest I can kill Mr. House? I've made sure to acquire and turn in all seven snow globes. Yes Man is waiting patiently outside The Tops for me. I still have the following quests open:

- How Little We Know
- Pressing Matters
- Oh My Papa
- Volare!
- I Put a Spell on You
- The Moon Comes Over the Tower
- Wild Card: Side Bets
- Wild Card: You and What Army?
- That Lucky Old Sun
- ED-E My Love

At which point have I "made my choice?" I know it's not too late *right now* to kill Mr. House. But if I finish any of the faction quests above, does it become so?

I should note that I'm at least "liked" by most factions, the notable exceptions being the Powder Gangers and the Legion (I finished "Booted" *after* getting the Mark of Caesar and the "Render Unto Caesar" quest -- thus I now have completed "Beware the Wrath of Caesar.")

How much farther on the quest lines above is it safe to go before I finally get around to whacking Mr. House and taking control of The Strip? I want to maximize my gameplay this first run-through! (Because the 100+ hours I've invested already isn't enough!)

Comment: One thing I recommend, I did it myself: Do everything you can before telling anyone what you did for the Boomers (Volare!) or killing Mr. House. Finish all quests, explore everything you haven't, etc. If you do a quest step and suddenly see several quests appear and fail, you went too far. Eventually you'll be down to just the four endgame paths. At that point you can create a save which you will use to do each of the four endings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with taking Yes-Man's path, you can basically wait until the very end to kill Mr. House. There is no need to take him out any sooner than the very absolute end.

The Legion and NCR, respectively, will want him out of the picture much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The latest is really the point of no return, assuming you don't alienate House beforehand by attacking him or something.

You get a warning from the game before you reach this point, at which you can decide to turn back and kill House. You'll probably get a quest objective from one of the factions to kill House earlier, but you shouldn't reach **that** point of no return if you're going for Wild Card.